# VM provioning using SharePoint

Tags: virtualization, sharepoint-2010

How to automate the creation of VM using sharepoint 2010?

This is the scenario, I already have a VM request eform in sharepoint. How to take in the input and create the VM using sharepoint. I know I have to link with the VMX file.

Thanks.

Comment: Which VMware product? Please consider changing the [vmware] tag on this with a product specific tag. This helps us better categorise questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really could have put a bit more effort into this question to be honest, in the future can you look at other questions and perhaps understand that we generally need more information that you've provided?

Anyway, what you're probably going to have to do is use some form of VM automation framework such as VMWare's Orchestrator (part of vCenter) and feed your SP form data into an Orchestrator workflow, then get that to do the work and send back confirmation emails with IPs, user IDs and passwords.

None of this is available right 'off the shelf' of course, you'll have to integrate them but this is definitely 'do'able'.

Comment: Yes, right now the answer is "programming". ;)

Comment: Haha - yes, couldn't have put it better myself - but at least I've told him what he needs to talk to. Guess he could talk directly to ESX via the Perl etc. API but given vCenter has Orchestrator it would have been wrong not to point at that first.